# c++ function call by value not work

Tags: c++, function, opencv, byval

I have a problem with this code:

The problem is when I see the image original, is modified by "borrarFondo()" but this function is called from "segmentarHoja" and here entry img by value, but img modifies.

```
void borrarFondo(Mat& img){
   img = ~img;
   Mat background;
   medianBlur(img, background, 45);
   GaussianBlur(background, background, Size(203,203),101,101);
   img = img - background;
   img = ~img;
}

void segmentarHoja(Mat img, Mat& imsheet){
   Mat imgbw;
   borrarFondo(img); //borrarFondo is called from here where img is a copy
   cvtColor(img, imgbw, CV_BGR2GRAY);
   threshold(imgbw, imgbw, 0, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY | CV_THRESH_OTSU);
   Mat element = getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(21,21));
   erode(imgbw, imgbw, element);
   vector<vector<Point> > contoursSheet; 
   findContours(imgbw, contoursSheet, CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
   vector<Rect> boundSheet(contoursSheet.size());
   int largest_area=0;

   for( int i = 0; i< contoursSheet.size(); i++ )
   {
        double a= contourArea( contoursSheet[i],false);
        if(a>largest_area){
           largest_area=a; 
           boundSheet[i] = boundingRect(contoursSheet[i]);
           imsheet=img(boundSheet[i]).clone(); 
        }
    }
    borrarFondo(imsheet);
  }

int main()
{
    Mat imsheet;
    image= imread("c:/imagen.jpg");
    segmentarHoja(image, imsheet);

    imshow("imsheet",imsheet);
    imshow("imagen",image); //original image by amending borrarFondo 
    waitKey(0);
}
```

I don't want to change original image

Comment: `void borrarFondo(Mat& img)` You didn't pass by value, you passed by reference. Which is why you modify `img`.

Comment: as far as i can recall opencv `Mat` is a reference counted reference (i.e. like `std::shared_ptr`, except different syntax) where copy construction or assignment does not copy. okay i just checked the docs now, which is what you should have done. use the `clone` method to copy.

Comment: @Cyber: no it isn't, although that would be a natural conclusion when knowing nothing about `Mat`.

Comment: but that function is called from other function "segmentarHoja" where img passed by value. In main call segmentarHoja and in segmentarhoja call borrarFondo, img change in segmentarHoja, but img in segmentarHoja passed by value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

opencv `Mat` is a counted reference (i.e. like `std::shared_ptr`, except different syntax) where copy construction or assignment does not copy. use the `clone` method to copy. read [the documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat), always a good idea.

Comment: then i can't pass `Mat` by value? should pass a copy of `Mat` with `clone` ?

Comment: By the way, I treated also this question and answer in keeping with my conviction that one has an obligation to teach correct stuff wherever one encounters misconceptions. But it gets tiring, and few care to do this anymore. So just be careful about advice you get on SO.

Comment: thanks for everything, i don't understand much english but i try learn all about image processing, and there aren't information of this in spanish xD, i have a project of school to make, I thought no better thing that something with opencv xD now i must do it

Comment: one more question, artificial intelligence is very complex? or in a month i understand it?

Comment: @user3779874: Consider that some of the best minds on the planet have struggled with researching and trying to create artificial intelligence since the 1950's, without yet succeeding, and you can conclude that there's a lot to learn. Notwithstanding that simple arithmetic tells you that it's still about 20 to 30 years or more till we have the necessary machine power. AI is the state of art of the state of the art, and it's very much a moving target... **BUT**, maybe you're talking about the "AI engine" of game. That's something much more practical, possible to learn about I think. :)

Comment: I mean AI for Optical Character Recognition, i don't mean to create artificial intelligence but use opencv to use existing algorithms AI using, i've seen a project about this, but I preferred to develop a ocr without this and now I see that is very outdated without this. If you know about OCR can i implement AI without knowing all about it? or be a waste of time?

Answer (score 1):

if you're doing something like this:

```
Mat a;
Mat b = a;
```

or like this:

```
void func(Mat m) {...}
```

or :

```
vector<Mat> vm; 
vm.push_back(m);
```

all of it is a *shallow* copy. the Mat header will be a copy, the pointers inside, too.

so, e.g. in the 1st example, b and a share the *same* size and data members

this might explain, why passing a Mat by value still results in pixels manipulated from the 'shallow' copy.

to avoid that you will have to do a 'deep' copy instead:

```
Mat c = a.clone(); // c has its own pixels now.
```

and again, if you don't want your Mat to be manipulated, <del>pass it as a `const Mat &`</del> be very careful about how you use it, as illustrated below.

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

void foo( cv::Mat const& image )
{
    cv::Mat result = image;
    cv::ellipse(
        result,                     // img
        cv::Point( 300, 300 ),        // center
        cv::Size( 50, 50 ),         // axes (bounding box size)
        0.0,                        // angle
        0.0,                        // startAngle
        360.0,                      // endAngle
        cv::Scalar_<int>( 0, 0, 255 ),  // color
        6                           // thickness
        );
}

auto main() -> int
{
    auto window_name = "Display";
    cv::Mat lenna = cv::imread( "lenna.png" );
    foo( lenna );
    imshow( window_name, lenna );
    cv::waitKey( 0 );
}
```

The `Mat const&` lied about mutability, and Lenna’s nose is correspondingly long, here marked by a big fat circle placed by the `foo` function above:

[image]